# How do you get an uploaded image removed/deleted?

Tags: support, questions

I uploaded a file before I properly cleaned off the content and what to have that file removed from the image repository.

How do I get it deleted from the image repository?  Note the relevant question is not displaying that message.

I click on the link to the image i can see it, but don't see any contact or delete options.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250344/delete-uploaded-image